# Adding MapAnnotations in SwiftUI 2 not conforming to MapAnnotationProtocol

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mapkit, core-location

I'm trying to add all the addresses returned from an API on to a map. Unfortunately the API doesn't return long/lat coordinates but I can retrieve them from the `geocodeAddressString` which when I place in the `List` outputs it correctly.

```swift
struct Locations: Decodable {
  let _id: Int
  let streetaddress: String?
  let suburb: String?
  let state: String?
  let postcode: String?
  func getCoordinates(handler: @escaping ((CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> Void)) {
    if let address = streetaddress, let suburb = suburb, let postcode = postcode, let state = state {
    CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString("\(address) \(suburb), \(state) \(postcode)") { ( placemark, error ) in
      handler(placemark?.first?.location?.coordinate ?? CLLocationCoordinate2D())
    }
  }
}
```

I have the network call going into a class (so I can use and call the data from other screens):

```swift
// minimised info
final class ModelData: ObservableObject {
  @Published var locations: [ModelRecord] = []
  func getLocationData() {
    // call the network
    self.locations = locations
  }
}
```

So in my main view I have a map which if I use normally is working okay (without annotations). But when I try to cycle the annotations in from the `getCoordinates()` function then it says it doesn't conform - which I'm assuming because of the loop in the loop.

```swift
struct MapView: View {
  @StateObject var mapViewModel = MapViewModel() // loads the map init
  @StateObject var modelData = ModelData()       // loads the api data
  var body: some View {
    Map(
      coordinateRegion: $mapViewModel.region,
      interactionModes: .all,
      showsUserLocation: true,
      annotationItems: modelData.locations,
      annotationContent: { location in
        location.getCoordinates() { i in
          MapPin(coordinate: i)
        }
      }
    )
    .onAppear { modelData. getLocationData() } // load data
  }
}
```

Is there any way to fix this so I can have locations appearing on the map? Everything I've read and watched is all about the reverse (having coordinates and getting address names).

Comment: Add conformance to the `MapAnnotationProtocol` to your `Locations` struct (which should be called `Location` since it represents a single location). You can't call an asynchronous method as part of your view. You need to perform the asynchronous work in your model and simply expose the coordinates as a property once you have them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, coordinates are only useful for MapPin (otherwise I imagine you would have created a `coordinates` property in your `Locations` struct).

In this case you could create a `Pin` struct (`Identifiable` to be able to be used by `Map`):

```
struct Pin: Identifiable {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    let id = UUID()
}
```

Now your View `MapView`, no longer displays an array of `Locations`, but an array of `Pin`. Its State is therefore a `[Pin]` (1). Which is first empty (we have no coordinates), and which is filled as we get the results of GeoCoder (2).

```
struct MapView: View {
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.862725, longitude: 2.287592), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05))

    @StateObject var modelData = ModelData() // loads the api data

    @State private var pins: [Pin] = [] // (1)
    var body: some View {
        Map(
            coordinateRegion: $region,
            interactionModes: .all,
            showsUserLocation: true,
            annotationItems: pins,
            annotationContent: { pin in
            MapPin(coordinate: pin.coordinate)
            }
        )
        .onAppear { modelData.getLocationData() } // load data
        .onChange(of: modelData.locations.isEmpty) { _ in
            for location in modelData.locations {
                location.getCoordinates { coordinate in
                    print("et voilà !")
                    pins.append(Pin(coordinate: coordinate)) // (2)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The struct `Locations` remains unchanged.
I tested with these data :

```
final class ModelData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var locations: [Locations] = []
    func getLocationData() {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.3) {
            self.locations = [.init(_id: 1, streetaddress: "11 rue Vineuse", suburb: "", state: "France", postcode: "75016"), .init(_id: 2, streetaddress: "11 rue Chardin", suburb: "", state: "France", postcode: "75016"), .init(_id: 3, streetaddress: "11 avenue Kléber", suburb: "", state: "France", postcode: "75016")]
        }        
    }
}
```

[image: example]

## EDIT : IOS15

For the first version, I was careful not to modify your Model. But we can now try to do better.

First, we will make sure that `Map` can take an array of `Locations` directly. We make `Locations` identifiable, and we add a `coordinate` property to it :

```
struct Locations: Decodable, Identifiable {
    let _id: Int
    let streetaddress: String?
    let suburb: String?
    let state: String?
    let postcode: String?

    var id: Int { _id }
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D? = nil

    private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case _id, streetaddress, suburb, state, postcode
    }
}
```

We take this opportunity to remove the function that uses Geocoder. Rather, it has its place in the class that fetch your data.

So I move it, and I take the opportunity to use async / await. This version will only work with Xcode13 / iOS15:

```
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
final class ModelData: ObservableObject {
    @Published var locations: [Locations] = []

    @MainActor
    func fetchLocationsWithCoordinates() async {
        let locations = await getLocationData()
        return await withTaskGroup(of: Locations.self) { group in
            for location in locations {
                group.async {
                    await self.updateCoordinate(of: location)
                }
            }
            for await location in group {
                self.locations.append(location)
            }
        }
    }

    private func updateCoordinate(of location: Locations) async -> Locations {
        var newLoc = location
        newLoc.coordinate = try? await CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(
            "\(location.streetaddress ?? "") \(location.suburb ?? ""), \(location.state ?? "") \(location.postcode ?? "")"
        ).first?.location?.coordinate
        //await Task.sleep(1_000_000_000)
        return newLoc
    }

    private func getLocationData() async -> [Locations] {
        //await Task.sleep(4_000_000_000)
        return [.init(_id: 1, streetaddress: "11 rue Vineuse", suburb: "", state: "France", postcode: "75016"), .init(_id: 2, streetaddress: "11 rue Chardin", suburb: "", state: "France", postcode: "75016"), .init(_id: 3, streetaddress: "11 avenue Kléber", suburb: "", state: "France", postcode: "75016")]
    }
}
```

Now in the `View`, I can call the function that retrieves the `Locations` and their `coordinates`, with the `.task()` modifier.

```
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
struct SwiftUIView15: View {
    @State private var region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.862725, longitude: 2.287592), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05))
    @StateObject var modelData = ModelData() // loads the api data
    var body: some View {
        Map(
            coordinateRegion: $region,
            interactionModes: .all,
            showsUserLocation: true,
            annotationItems: modelData.locations,
            annotationContent: { pin in
                MapPin(coordinate: pin.coordinate ?? CLLocationCoordinate2D())
            }
        )
        .task {
            await modelData.fetchLocationsWithCoordinates()
        }
    }
}
```

It's cleaner.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I get a "Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior." ERROR as well as making update on background thread error. HMMMM

Comment: I only have this warning if I remove the @MainActor attribute. 
Don't forget to use it for the object or functions that are supposed to act on the UI.

Comment: I also get tons of "Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior." errors with Xcode 14.2. And I added the @MainActor attribute. What version are you testing this with?

Comment: Xcode 14.2
Note that can add @MainActor attribute to the entire class.